# Converting listeners to closures in groovy

Tags: android, groovy

I've decided to convert my android project to groovy. I'm new to Groovy and trying to use some of Groovy's magic to make the code readable.

One of the code fragments I'm trying to convert is anonymous OnXXXClickListener.

So how do I convert something like

```
_children.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            void onItemClick(
                    final AdapterView<?> parent,
                    final View view, final int position, final long id) {

            }
        })
```

to something more readable with closures

Found this - http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.il/2013/11/groovy-goodness-implicit-closure.html

and tried using

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = {foo}
```

however I'm getting `Cannot assign closure to OnItemClickListener`

Comment: You should be able to do:

_children.onOnItemClickListener = { ... }

Even

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = { ... }

should work. Is this the IDE saying it is not allowed or the build failing?

Comment: Yes, using Android studio

Comment: I mean does the Gradle build fail?

Comment: You are right gradle succeeds. Should I open a bug somewhere ?

Comment: Looks like after writing the full closure it's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the full closure and Android studio accepted it without any errors.

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = { 
        parent, view, long position, id -> 
    startActivity(
        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChildDetails.class)
            .putExtra( ChildDetails.CHILD_NAME, position ))
}
_children.setOnItemClickListener listener
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure about "android on groovy", but in the plain groovy I'd put id down so:

```
def closure = { parent, view, long position, id -> yourCode() }
_children.onItemClickListener = [ onItemClick:closure ] as OnItemClickListener
```